# Is it possible to have java detect if a program is an active window?

Tags: java, eclipse, twitch

So I'm coding a side project that involves Twitch chat using commands to play games on my PC. The question I have is, I want it to recognize if a window is active then do something. Just for a random example, let's say that MS Paint is open. If another window is active, the chat won't be able to use commands anymore. but when it's active again, they can. Does anyone have any ideas on how to approach this? If I had to write pseudo-code:

```
if (window.active("MS PAINT"){
     // do something
}
```

Any hints or points in a direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I think it is OS dependant, you can't do that with only java call or method. But I guess you are on windows so maybe you can take a look to JNA and `GetForegroundWindow()`